# Pic/Sharing Showing on News Feed

Tags: facebook

When I add photos or share things on facebook, I can see them on my timeline but they are not showing on the news feed.  How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this. You won't see your own updates on your news feed after a change that Facebook made to it's news feeds.

This answer is timely and may change if Facebook changes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just shared a photo in my timeline and it's now showing in the newsfeed as well. Maybe you can trying change the default sort order in the newsfeed from "Top Stories" to "Most Recent"